# gte date update nested property failed in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Stuck for hours settling this issue but failed. Not sure is the date problem.

This is how many data look like

[image]

I plan to update multiple documents by date range, but eventually I found this not even working.

```
db.trucks.update({'data.date': {'$gte': '2017-01-04T16:00:00.000Z'}}, 
    {'$set': {'data.$.price':100}})
```

I even tried to pass just the string

```
db.trucks.update({'data.date': {'$gte': '1/4/2017'}}, 
    {'$set': {'data.$.price':100}})
```

I got `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

Comment: You have to use date object for $gte condition. you are using string date and pass third parameters as object {"multi":true} in query for multi update

Comment: not sure but try putting the date inside a new Date() function, like var date = new Date("xxx-xxx-xxx"); then pass that date, again I am not so sure.db.trucks.update({'data.date': {'$gte': date}},

Comment: @AnkitAneja please post an answer? I don't get what you means

Comment: Are you using mongo shell or any tool.

Comment: @sacDahal tried that, doesn't work, not the issue.

Comment: @AnkitAneja mongochef, it's the same with mongo.

Comment: why not try a find command and see if its a date issue or an update issue.

Comment: @sacDahal solved. I do new Date('1-1-2016'). But still failed to do for range date, $lte doesn't worked :(. `Trucks.update({'data.date': {'$gte': startDate, '$lte': endDate}}, 
    {'$set': update}, 
    {multi:true})` why??